# Binding several attributes to the same element

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<a href="#/{{unbound goto}}" {{bind-attr class=":menu-entry-text :nowrap active:selected-menu-entry-text"}} {{bind-attr id="active:active-nav:inactive-nav"}} {{bind-attr data-goto="goto"}}>
```

But only the first attribute (`class`) gets set: `id` and `data-goto` are not defined. Is it possible to set several attributes with `bind-attr` in the same element? How?

Comment: If you have a need for a rather "big" amount of bindings you probably should consider making an own `View` or `Component` class for this purpose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can bind several attributes at once by either using multiple `bind-attr` helpers like in your example, or just putting all the attributes in a single `bind-attr` helper. You have an issue in your example though, which is why things aren't working as expected.

The "value if true" form that you're using for the class attribute cannot be applied to other types of attributes. All other attributes must be bound to a dynamic property on the controller. For example, if you had a controller that looked like this:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  myId: function() {
    if (this.get("active") === true) {
      "active-nav"
    } else {
      "inactive-nav"
    }
  }.property("active")
});
```

Then you would bind that like so:

```
<a href="#/{{unbound goto}}" {{bind-attr id="myID"}}>
```

Just a side note on that example, it's probably a code smell if you have a dynamic ID for an HTML element. IDs are supposed to uniquely identify a single element and I wouldn't expect them to change. It seems like a class would be a better fit for this use case.

Comment: Thanks, that is working. Using a hard-coded ID is the only way I have found to override some CSS styles set by twitter bootstrap. Since bootstrap is quite specific, and the CSS specificity rules are what they are, it is difficult to override without using an ID. I'll try to define more specific overrides, but that is not easy.